# join two files though IDs do not totally match

Tags: text-processing

Does anybody know how to join two files, keeping unmatched lines too? For example,

File 1:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

File 2:

```
b tsd gills 2000
e ffe jjoog 1928
```

I want to make an output file as below.
Output

```
a
b tsd gills 2000
c
d
e ffe jjoog 1928
```

If I do as below, I cannot keep the unmatched ID's lines.

```
join file1 file2 > Output

Output is as below
b tsd gills 2000
e ffe jjoog 1928
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
join -a 1 file1 file2
```

as per `man join`

> -a FILENUM 
> print unpairable lines coming from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is 1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2